# Lifetime of variables passed to a new thread

Tags: rust

I have trouble compiling this program:

```
use std::env;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().skip(1).collect();

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for arg in &args {
        let t = tx.clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
            let _new_arg = arg.to_string() + "foo";
            t.send(arg);
        });
    }

    for _ in &args {
        println!("{}", rx.recv().unwrap());
    }
}
```

I read all arguments from the command line and emulate doing some work on each argument in the thread. Then I print out the results of this work, which I do using a channel.

```
error[E0597]: `args` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     for arg in &args {
   |                 ^^^^ does not live long enough
...
24 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

If I understood well.. the lifetime of `args` must be `static` (i.e. the entire time of program execution), while it only lives within the scope of `main` function (?). I don't understand the reason behind this, and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in spawning a background thread. When you call `thread::spawn` you effectively have to pass ownership of any resource used in it to the thread, as it might run indefinitely, which means that its lifetime must be `'static`.

There are two options to resolve that: the simplest one would be to pass ownership. Your code here

```
let new_arg = arg.to_string() + "foo";
t.send(arg);
```

looks like you actually wanted to send `new_arg`, in which case you could just create the owned result of `arg.to_string()` before spawning the thread, thus eliminating the need to pass the reference `arg`.

Another slightly more involved idea, that might be useful at some point though, are scoped threads as implemented in [crossbeam](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam/) for example. These are bound to an explicit scope, where you spawn them and are joined together at the end. This looks somewhat like this:

```
crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
    scope.spawn(|| {
        println!("Hello from a scoped thread!");
    });
});
```

Have a look at [the docs](http://aturon.github.io/crossbeam-doc/crossbeam/struct.Scope.html) for further details.

Comment: Since the vector is a collection of `String`s and not used after spawning the threads, I'd just move `arg` as-is into the thread - [example](http://is.gd/CMhQ7t). In fact, I might even eschew the collection into the `Vec` at all - [example](http://is.gd/vQcgWI).

Comment: Thank you @Shepmaster and aepsil0n, it really clicked for me this time. [crossbeam::Scope.spawn()](http://aturon.github.io/crossbeam-doc/crossbeam/struct.Scope.html#method.spawn) also nicely explains this very problem.