# How to return a future combinator with `&self`

Tags: rust, future, lifetime

I have this piece of code using futures v0.1:

```
impl ArcService for (Box<MiddleWare<Request>>, Box<ArcService>) {
    fn call(&self, req: Request, res: Response) -> Box<Future<Item = Response, Error = Error>> {
        box self.0.call(req).and_then(move |req| self.1.call(req, res))
    }
}

pub trait ArcService: Send + Sync {
    fn call(&self, req: Request, res: Response) -> Box<Future<Item = Response, Error = Error>>;
}

pub trait MiddleWare<T>: Sync + Send {
    fn call<'a>(&'a self, param: T) -> Box<Future<Item = T, Error = Error> + 'a>;
}

type MiddleWareFuture<'a, I> = Box<Future<Item = I, Error = Error> + 'a>;

impl MiddleWare<Request> for Vec<Box<MiddleWare<Request>>> {
    fn call(&self, request: Request) -> MiddleWareFuture<Request> {
        self.iter()
            .fold(box Ok(request).into_future(), |request, middleware| {
                box request.and_then(move |req| middleware.call(req))
            })
    }
}

pub struct ArcRouter {
    routes: HashMap<Method, Box<ArcService>>,
}

// Service implementation
impl hyper::Server::Service for ArcRouter {
    type Response = Response;
    type Request = Request;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, req: Request) -> Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>> {
        if let Some(routeMatch) = self.matchRoute(req.path(), req.method()) {
            let mut request: ArcRequest = req.into();
            request.paramsMap.insert(routeMatch.params);
            let response = routeMatch.handler //handler is ArcService
                    .call(request, ArcResponse::new())
                    .map(|res| res.into());
            return box response;
        }

        // TODO: this should be handled by a user defined 404 handler
        return box Ok(Response::new().with_status(StatusCode::NotFound)).into_future();
    }
}
```

Note the lifetime parameter on `Middleware` — it is used to avoid lifetime issues.

This does not compile because `Box<Future<Item = Response, Error = Error>>` is implicitly `'static` and therefore causes lifetime issues. `hyper::Server::Service` requires a `'static Future`

Here is an example that aptly describes my problem:

```
extern crate futures; // v0.1 (old)

use futures::{future, Future};

struct Example {
    age: i32,
}

// trait is defined in an external crate. You can't change it's definition
trait MakeFuture {
    fn make_a_future(&self) -> Box<Future<Item = i32, Error = ()>>;
}

impl MakeFuture for Example {
    fn make_a_future(&self) -> Box<Future<Item = i32, Error = ()>> {
        let f = future::ok(self).map(|ex| ex.age + 1);
        Box::new(f)
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0e555b8928130f1b93766b0c10813b22&version=stable)

which gives the lifetime error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:16:28
   |
16 |         let f = future::ok(self).map(|ex| ex.age + 1);
   |                            ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 15:5...
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 | /     fn make_a_future(&self) -> Box<Future<Item = i32, Error = ()>> {
16 | |         let f = future::ok(self).map(|ex| ex.age + 1);
17 | |         Box::new(f)
18 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected &Example, found &Example)
  --> src/main.rs:16:28
   |
16 |         let f = future::ok(self).map(|ex| ex.age + 1);
   |                            ^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Item=i32, Error=()> + 'static>, found std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Item=i32, Error=()>>)
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         Box::new(f)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to get around this? I'm building with `hyper::Service` and using Rust v1.25.0 (nightly)

Comment: *implicitly `'static`* — I see you've used the syntax `Box<Future<Item = I, Error = Error> + 'a>` in one case; why haven't you used that everywhere that needs it?

Comment: @Shepmaster I would eventually need a `'static` `Box<<Future<Item = I, Error = Error>>` because `hyper::server::Service` requires it. see https://docs.rs/tokio-service/0.1.0/tokio_service/trait.Service.html

Comment: I'm unclear what your end goal is with the question, then. Presumably you have already become experienced with basic Rust and lifetimes before attempting even harder topics like multithreading / asynchronous IO. If you contain a reference to anything, you cannot meet the `'static` bounds. This has nothing to do with futures.

Comment: check the edit.

Comment: There are many ways to get around lifetime problems, but that isn't really related to `Future`s and combinators.  In short: get rid of the references.  Move your values, clone them, clone `Rc`/`Arc` pointers to them, ... - or keep track of the involved lifetimes through everything (`Box<T + 'a>`...).  Usually not worth the effort, and with `Future`s not possible (because you can't spawn non-`'static` futures on most event loops).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to return a future combinator with `&self`

You return a future that refers to `self` like this:

```
use futures::future::{self, FutureResult}; // 0.1.28

struct Example {
    age: i32,
}

impl Example {
    fn make_a_future(&self) -> FutureResult<&Example, ()> {
        future::ok(self)
    }
}
```

As discussed in the [Tokio documentation on returning futures](https://tokio.rs/docs/futures/combinators/#returning-futures/), the easiest stable solution to returning a complicated future is a *impl Trait*. Note that we assign an explicit lifetime to `self` and use that in the returned value (via `+ 'a`):

```
use futures::{future, Future}; // 0.1.28

struct Example {
    age: i32,
}

impl Example {
    fn make_a_future<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Future<Item = i32, Error = ()> + 'a {
        future::ok(self).map(|ex| ex.age + 1)
    }
}
```

---

Your **real** question is "how can I lie to the compiler and attempt to introduce memory unsafety into my program?"

`Box<SomeTrait + 'static>` (or `Box<SomeTrait>` by itself) means that the trait object **must not** contain any references that do not last for the entire program. By definition, your `Example` struct has a shorter lifetime than that.

**This has nothing to do with futures**. This is a fundamental Rust concept.

There are many questions that ask the same thing in regards to threads, which have similar restrictions. A small sampling:

- [Lifetime of variables passed to a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34439977/155423)
- [How do I use static lifetimes with threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30562443/155423)
- [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423)
- [Lifetime troubles sharing references between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28654978/155423)

Like in those cases, you are attempting to share a reference to a variable with something that may exist **after** the variable is destroyed. Languages such as C or C++ would *let you do this*, only to have your program crash at a seemingly random point in time in the future when that variable is accessed after being freed. The crash is the *good* case, by the way; information leaks or code execution is also possible.

Like the case for threads, you have to ensure that this doesn't happen. The easiest way is to move the variable into the future, not sharing it at all. Another option is to use something like an `Arc` around your variable, clone the `Arc` and hand the clone to the future.

Comment: Thank you for this example, I've updated my question with an example that properly reflects my problems.