# Using program arguments within a thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am having issues passing command-line arguments into threads so have constructed this program which illustrates my issue.

```
use std::env;
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
  let stdout = io::stdout();

  let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
  let arg = &args[1];

  let thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    writeln!(stdout.lock(), "argument was \"{}\"", arg).unwrap();
  });

  thread.join().unwrap();
}
```

However, the compiler gives me the following error when I try to compile this...

```
error[E0597]: `args` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:9:14
   |
9  |   let arg = &args[1];
   |              ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
16 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

I am unsure as to how to compile a program like this. I understand the the `&str` created by `&args[1]` does not have a static lifetime so cannot be passed into the thread. However, what options are there for passing in program arguments into a thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lifetime of variables passed to a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34439977/5223757)

Comment: Thanks @wizzwizz4, that's just what I was trying to find!

Comment: See also the additional duplicate.

Comment: @Zak In which case, can you click the "this answered my question" button? Edit: Never mind; you have.