# How can I thread using functions using method in self?

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing, rayon

When trying to write some paralel code I keep getting hit with the error seen bellow. There are a few solutions I have found but they all involve locking which I would prefer not to do. Is there any way I can get round this?

```rust
pub trait PermBrute {
    fn quadgram( &self, max_len: usize, ciphertext: &String ) -> Vec<usize> {
        let mut vec : Vec<(f64, Vec<usize>)> = Vec::new();
        let results = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec));
        let mut threads = vec![];

        for i in 0..*CPUS {
            threads.push( thread::spawn({
                let clone = Arc::clone(&results);
                let text = ciphertext.clone();
                move || {
                    // some code here
                    let hold = self.decrypt( )
                    // some more code here

                    let mut v = clone.lock().unwrap();
                    v.push(best_key);
                }
            }));
        }

        for t in threads {
            t.join().unwrap();
        }

        let lock = Arc::try_unwrap(results).expect("Lock still has multiple owners");
        let mut hold = lock.into_inner().expect("Mutex cannot be locked");

        // do some stuff with hold and return out

        return out;
    }

    fn decrypt( &self, ciphertext : &String, key : &Vec<usize>) -> String;
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `Self` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/ciphers/cipher.rs:131:27
    |
108 |     fn quadgram( &self, max_len: usize, ciphertext: &String ) -> Vec<usize> {
    |                                                                            - help: consider further restricting `Self`: `where Self: std::marker::Sync`
...
131 |             threads.push( thread::spawn({
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Self` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `Self`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&Self`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/ciphers/cipher.rs:140:17: 164:18 text:std::string::String, start_len:usize, end_len:usize, count:usize, start_points_clone:std::vec::Vec<usize>, local_self:&Self, end:usize, clone:std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<std::vec::Vec<(f64, std::vec::Vec<usize>)>>>]`
```

Comment: You can do this with the rayon library.

Comment: How would I use rayon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/) crate, this can be done using the parallel iterator technique.

```
pub trait PermBrute {
    fn quadgram(&self, max_len: usize, ciphertext: &String) -> Vec<usize> {
        let mut vec: Vec<(f64, Vec<usize>)> = Vec::new();
        let mut threads = vec![];
        
        let best_keys: Vec<_> = (0..*CPUS)
            .into_par_iter()
            .map(|i| {
                // some code here
                // you can access `ciphertext` here directly without copying
                todo!();
                // some more code here
                
                best_key
            })
            .collect();

        // do some stuff with best_keys and return out

        return out;
    }
    fn decrypt(&self, ciphertext: &String, key: &Vec<usize>) -> String;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me sometime to modify your code so that I can test it on rust playground. Here's the modified source code:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

pub trait PermBrute {
    fn quadgram( &self, max_len: usize, ciphertext: &String ) -> Vec<usize> {
        let mut vec : Vec<(f64, Vec<usize>)> = Vec::new();
        let results = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec));
        let mut threads = vec![];

        for i in 0..10 {
            threads.push( thread::spawn({
                let clone = Arc::clone(&results);
                let text = ciphertext.clone();
                move || {
                    // some code here
                    let hold = self.decrypt( &String::new(), &vec![] );
                    // some more code here

                    let mut v = clone.lock().unwrap();
                    // v.push(best_key);
                }
            }));
        }

        for t in threads {
            t.join().unwrap();
        }

        let lock = Arc::try_unwrap(results).expect("Lock still has multiple owners");
        let mut hold = lock.into_inner().expect("Mutex cannot be locked");

        // do some stuff with hold and return out

        // return out;
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn decrypt(&self, ciphertext: &String, key: &Vec<usize>) -> String;
}
```

First, you may restrict `Self` by:

```
pub trait PermBrute: Sync {}
```

Then, `rustc` starts to bother about lifetimes:

(the error is too long, and I'm then using [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a4fe89bfdd4b8046e8ac1641148b489))

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439977/lifetime-of-variables-passed-to-a-new-thread) should answer your question. In short, `thread`s are spawned background, and `rustc` is still stupid and does not regard your `join`s. There are workarounds like `Arc<Self>` or `AtomicPtr<Self>`.

---

#### Update

Let us start with a minimal example:

```rust
use std::thread;

fn try_to_spawn() {
    let x: String = "5".to_string();
    let j = thread::spawn(|| {
        println!("{}", x.len());
    });
    j.join().unwrap();
}
```

Here, `rustc` says:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/lib.rs:5:27
  |
5 |     let j = thread::spawn(|| {
  |                           ^^ may outlive borrowed value `x`
6 |         println!("{}", x.len());
  |                        - `x` is borrowed here
  |

help: to force the closure to take ownership of `x` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
5 |     let j = thread::spawn(move || {
  |                           ^^^^
```

Here `rustc` complains about lifetime of borrowed `x`. `rustc` thinks that: since a thread is spawned and will be running background, it could terminate either before or after function `try_to_spawn` exits, so `x` may be dangling when `x.len()` gets executed.

But obviously, we `join`ed the thread at the end of function, and our `x` definitely lives long enough (of course, `'static` life time is not required, at human's point of view). However, `rustc` is still too stupid to understand human, and it does not know something about our `join`!.

It is OK to move `x` into closure, instead of borrowing it. It will be impossible to use `x` in further time, however. To solve the problem in "safe" way, you use `Arc<String>`:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn try_to_spawn() {
    let x: Arc<String> = Arc::new("5".to_string());
    let x_clone: Arc<String> = x.clone();
    let j = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("{}", x_clone.len());
    });
    j.join().unwrap();
    println!("{}", x.len());
}
```

But `Arc` has overheads. One may want to use pointers `*const String` or `*mut String` in order to avoid lifetime checks -- raw pointers are not `Send`/`Sync` and cannot be transferred to a `thread`, however. To share resource via pointer between threads, you must use `AtomicPtr` ([here](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/shouldnt-pointers-be-send-sync-or/8818) is a discussion about making raw pointers to `Send + Sync`).

---

So back to the question, what about your `self` (of type `&Self`)? Of course, it is also a reference! And `rustc` also fails to figure out its "true lifetime":

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct S;

impl S {
    fn try_to_spawn(&self) {
        let j = thread::spawn(|| {
            self.do_something();
        });
        j.join().unwrap();
    }
    
    fn do_something(&self) {}
}
```

yields the error information:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:8:31
   |
8  |           let j = thread::spawn(|| {
   |  _______________________________^
9  | |             self.do_something();
10 | |         });
   | |_________^
   |
```

This one does not look like the previous lifetime error, but more similar to the one occurred in your code. To resolve this issue, again, you may use `Arc<Self>`:

```
fn try_to_spawn(self: Arc<Self>) {
    let j = thread::spawn(move || {
        self.do_something();
    });
    j.join().unwrap();
}
```

or use `AtomicPtr<Self>`:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicPtr;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed;

struct S;

impl S {
    fn try_to_spawn(&self) {
        let self_ptr: AtomicPtr<Self> 
            = AtomicPtr::new(self as *const Self as *mut Self);
        let j = thread::spawn(move || {
            unsafe {
                self_ptr.load(Relaxed) // *mut Self
                    .as_ref()          // Option<&Self>
                    .unwrap()          // &Self
                    .do_something();
            }
        });
        j.join().unwrap();
    }
    
    fn do_something(&self) {}
}
```

This works but ugly. And I also suggest using crates like `rayon` to perform parallel computations. However, I still hope this answer is helpful, for circumstances you'd like to create `thread`s manually.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry that it was not in a form that could be tested, will keep that in mind for next time. I'm not sure if i am just being stupid, but cannot figure out at all where to put `Arc<Self>` or `AtomicPtr<Self>` in the code. Had a look at the linked post, but still do not understand.

Comment: Updated, hope that helps~